# Is there a generic type that contains any Object class and a List<Object> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to initialize a class with Reflection and a Map (This due a more complex requirement, I just isolated the example)

```
public class ParentDto {
    private String field1;
    private BigDecimal field2;
    private List<AClass> listField3;
}
```

I created a map to set values for the first 2 fields with a generic value Map

```
public static final Map<String, Object> INITIALIZER = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry("field1", "String"),
    Map.entry("field2", new BigDecimal("23.43")
```

However, if i try to do the same for the list it will fail. It makes sense since Object is not a Base Class for List. My question is: Is there any way I can add

```
Map.entry("listField3", List.of("e1","e2"))
```

into my static map? A superclass that have in common both Objects and List

Comment: Have you tried this? Object IS a superclass of List, so this just works.

Comment: @Sören Oh wow. Because of your comment i rechecked my code and it seems that I just had an extra parenthesis, I also thought that about Object being a super class that includes List, but overthought it instead going to the basics. Thank you!!

Comment: Side note: you only need `Map.entry(…)` when you want to initialize a map with more than ten entries (or truly have a need for `Map.Entry` instances themselves). For the simple cases, you can just write `public static final Map<String, Object> INITIALIZER = Map.of("field1", "String", "field2", new BigDecimal("23.43"), "listField3", List.of("e1","e2"));`